# Getting a segfault

Tags: c

So the general idea is to be able to store objects in a dynamically allocated memory, and I'm doing so by passing a struct `msg` to `QueueSend()`. (simulating how it's done in FreeRTOS kernel), but I'm seeing a segfault after memcopying the struct.

```c
typedef struct {
  int type;
  char buff[20];
} msg_t;

int main(void) {

  msg_t msg;
  memset(msg.buff, 'C', 19);

  xQueue = CreateQueue(10, sizeof(msg));
  QueueSend(xQueue , &msg);
}


typedef struct {
  int8_t *pcHead;
  int8_t *writeTo;
  int8_t *readFrom;

  uint8_t uxLength;
  uint8_t uxItemSize;
} QueueHandle;

QueueHandle *CreateQueue(uint8_t queueLength, uint8_t itemSize)
{
  QueueHandle *pxNewQueue;
  size_t sizeInBytes = itemSize * queueLength;
  pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue) + sizeInBytes);

  pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) pxNewQueue;
  pxNewQueue->writeTo = pxNewQueue->pcHead;
  pxNewQueue->uxItemSize = itemSize;
  pxNewQueue->uxLength = queueLength;

  return pxNewQueue;

}

void QueueSend(QueueHandle *queue, const void * pvItem)
{
  (void)memcpy((void*)queue->writeTo, pvItem, (queue->uxItemSize));

  printf ("(queueSend): %s\n", (char*)queue->writeTo);  // segment fault
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: This is missing the definition for `QueueHandle`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `(void)memcpy(...)`?

Comment: What is `pcHead`? Is it a NUL terminated C string? If not, `%s` cannot deal with it. You can't just slap a cast on it and expect it to work. I'm really confused by this code. Why does `pxNewQueue->pcHead` point to *itself*? Either that's a structure or it's a C string. It can't be both.

Comment: It's missing  a lot of things, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `pcHead` is pointing to the allocated memory on heap

Comment: `pxNewQueue->writeTo = pxNewQueue->pcHead;` makes no sense as it is the queue object!

Comment: @4386427 this part of the snippet was taken from the freeRTOS kernel. I was trying to understand the code by doing something similar

Comment: I think you mangled something in the translation because this code can't work in its current form. It's worth carefully checking the original to see how the allocations are done.

Answer (score 2):

WAG
this:

```
pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) pxNewQueue;
```

Should be:

```
pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) (pxNewQueue+1);
```

It makes no sense to set the write pointer (writeTo) to be the control structure.

This is idiomatic C, has been a pattern for ages.

The allocation will be `sizeof(*x) + n`.   The `sizeof(*x)` accounts for the size and alignment of `*x;` as can be shown by mallocing an array of x via:

```
x = malloc(n*sizeof(*x));
for (i = 0;  i < n; i++) x[i] = 0;
```

So, the buffer sits at (x+1) which you can safely cast into any type which does not require a more strict alignment than x.  In your case (int8_t *); it is fine.

Comment: @tadman now how did pointer arithmetic work in C...

Comment: This presumes `sizeof()` and `alignof()` are the same, which may not be true. I'd expect `pxNewQueue+1` to be +32, not +26 as you expect. Unless the buffer allocation accounts for this padding, it'll walk off the end of the allocation.

Comment: sorry but can you elaborate on adding an offset here?

Comment: @tadman `sizeof(*pxNewQueue)` will include any alignment requirement, i.e. `pxNewQueue+1` will increase the **byte address** with exactly `sizeof(*pxNewQueue)`. In other words - I think this approach is fine.

Comment: @4386427 Ah, fair enough. In that case there's some wasted memory at the end of the structure.

Comment: @tadman For instance `struct x {int a; char b;}` will often have size 8. And `struct x {int a; char b; char c}` will also often have size 8, i.e. 3 (or 2) bytes padding to get alignment correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying is to create a **flexible array member**

Try like:

```
typedef struct {
  int8_t *writeTo;
  int8_t *readFrom;

  uint8_t uxLength;
  uint8_t uxItemSize;
  int8_t pcHead[];    // Flexible array - notice that no size is given
                      //                - notice must be last member
} QueueHandle;
```

Then this alloc is ok:

```
pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue) + sizeInBytes);
```

That is: `pcHead` can now be used as a buffer that has `sizeInBytes` bytes.

And then you initialize the read and write pointers like:

```
pxNewQueue->writeTo = pcHead;
pxNewQueue->readFrom= pcHead;
```

(assuming that equal value means "empty")

BTW: I would assume that `QueueSend` should include some update of `writeTo` in order to point to the next free location.

However, **if you prefer the original struct as it is in your code**, you should do as suggested by

@tadman: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63568285/4386427

```
pxNewQueue->pcHead = ((int8_t*)pxNewQueue) + sizeof(*pxNewQueue);
```

or by

@mevets: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63568252/4386427

```
pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) (pxNewQueue+1);
```

but I think the flexible array is a much more clear implementation.

(note: If you prefer the solution suggested be either @tadman or @mevets, remember to accept that answer - not mine)

**oh.. and why did you get a seg fault?**

Here:

```
pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) pxNewQueue; // pcHead points to malloc'ed memory
pxNewQueue->writeTo = pxNewQueue->pcHead;  // now writeTo does the same
```

Then

```
memcpy((void*)queue->writeTo, pvItem, (queue->uxItemSize));
```

will overwrite the `QueueHandle` object with the message, i.e. you overwrite `pcHead`, `writeTo`, ... and so on.

Then:

```
printf ("(queueSend): %s\n", (char*)queue->writeTo);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    This pointer has just been overwritten
                                    So it's no longer valid
                                    Seg fault...
```

Comment: This approach is a lot better in terms of understandability.

Comment: So...the idea is to have `writeTo` point `pcHead` where the `pcHead` is just an empty array. I rechecked the kernel code and I see `pcHead` gets pointed to `sizeof( QueueHandle)`...not sure why. Aren't we supposed to have a queue that contains X number of structs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing your allocations here:

```
// Allocate the structure
pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue));

// Allocate the buffer
pxNewQueue->pcHead = calloc(queueLength, itemSize);
```

Where now you have a buffer allocated independently. You might be able to do this with a single allocation and some pointer math to walk to the end of the structure but that just confuses your code:

```
// Allocate the structure
pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue) + queueLength * itemSize);

// Allocate the buffer
pxNewQueue->pcHead = ((int8_t*)pxNewQueue) + sizeof(*pxNewQueue);
```

That just looks plain confusing and is not very maintainable.

Don't forget to `return` the pointer as Andrew points out.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
QueueHandle *CreateQueue(uint8_t queueLength, uint8_t itemSize)
{
  QueueHandle *pxNewQueue;
  size_t sizeInBytes = itemSize * queueLength;
  pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue) + sizeInBytes);

  pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) pxNewQueue;
  pxNewQueue->writeTo = pxNewQueue->pcHead;
  pxNewQueue->uxItemSize = itemSize;
  pxNewQueue->uxLength = queueLength;

}
```

is missing a `return` statement.

Did you mean

```
QueueHandle *CreateQueue(uint8_t queueLength, uint8_t itemSize)
{
  QueueHandle *pxNewQueue;
  size_t sizeInBytes = itemSize * queueLength;
  pxNewQueue = malloc(sizeof(*pxNewQueue) + sizeInBytes);

  pxNewQueue->pcHead = (int8_t*) pxNewQueue;
  pxNewQueue->writeTo = pxNewQueue->pcHead;
  pxNewQueue->uxItemSize = itemSize;
  pxNewQueue->uxLength = queueLength;

  return( pxNewQueue );
}
```